# Order of callbacks: setTimeout and ResizeObserver

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dom, non-deterministic

With the following code I sometimes get `timeout`, then `RO` output, sometimes the reverse. Are both valid browser behaviours? Or just one?

```js
const div = document.createElement("div")
document.body.append(div)
new ResizeObserver(() => console.log("RO")).observe(div)
setTimeout(() => console.log("timeout"))
```

It happens in Firefox. In Midori, which also uses Gecko, it seems to be always `timeout` first.

**EDIT:**
Simpler code also showing this:

```
new ResizeObserver(() => console.log("RO")).observe(document.body)
setTimeout(() => console.log("timeout"))
```

**EDIT:**
Jake Archibald's [article](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/) and other materials indicate, IIUC, that the observers should run first. That is, assuming that `ResizeObserver` queues a microtask, like `MutationObserver` does. Alas, the [Editor's Draft for `ResizeObserver`](https://drafts.csswg.org/resize-observer/) seems silent on that.

Comment: I also see the variation in Chrome.

Comment: "*Are both valid browser behaviours?*" - sure, why not? Why do you care?

Comment: @Bergi, I want to isolate resize observations caused by third party code inside the observed elements. So whenever my code does something that may resize them, I set a flag that's tested by the RO callback. But I don't know if after my code runs, the callback will be called; sometimes it won't. I want to run another callback afterwards (or just it if there was no RO callback call) which resets the flag.

Comment: @ByteEater I recommend that instead of a flag that you need to toggle back, you stored the desired state of the DOM. Then in your observer callback, you don't check whether the flag is unset, but rather whether the DOM matches the desired state. You never have to reset the state that way, and as an additional benefit, it lets you detect when the third-party code did stuff right after your own code ran but before the observer callback.

Comment: @Bergi, I'm afraid I don't know the desired state yet at that earlier moment.

Comment: I've edited to propose for verification by the community that `RO` is output from a microtask callback and should therefore be first.

Comment: @ByteEater "*I don't know the desired state yet*" - sure you do: after you did "*something [to the elements] that may resize them*", you remember that current state of the DOM. That might be tagging the elements as created by you, storing the values of the DOM properties modified by you, or in extreme keeping a copy of the whole observed subtree. Then when the resize observer fires, you can compare the DOM (that might have been modified by the third party) with the stored (intended) value.

Comment: Oh, you mean, store the thing whose change is observed, i.e. the sizes of relevant elements? Yea, that would work. The code would be significantly longer than with relying on the ordering, but if it's unreliable, then at least this is how it's possible. Thanks for the idea! (Btw, I don't make the changes, it's relayout when the viewport is resized, which may lead to (but it's unknown in advance and may depend on the browser) some elements being resized. But I can implement your suggestion in `onresize` handler.) As for your first comment, are you still sure, having read my edit to the question

Comment: @ByteEater I meant to store the values of DOM properties that affect the sizes, not the sizes themselves (as accessing those requires a reflow), but I suppose that works as well. You say you "*want to isolate resize observations caused by third party code inside the observed elements*", I thought that the third party code is making the changes (whose effects) you want to observe?

Comment: @ByteEater "*As for your first comment, are you still sure*" - I don't see anything in the linked pages indicating that the resize observer callback is scheduled as a microtask. I would have assumed it's called as part of a normal task (or directly during the layouting task), which means the browser can prioritise it like it wants against the timer task.

Comment: Fair enough. I've just checked that `IntersectionObserver` queues tasks (unlike `MutationObserver`), so there seems to be no consistency. `ResizeObserver` should be treated as still underspecified. And apparently browsers queue tasks.

Comment: But what you suggest amounts to partially reimplementing `ResizeObserver`. I've come up with another solution: `observe = false; requestAnimationFrame(() => requestAnimationFrame(() => observe = true))` (nested rAF, to be sure the observer handler has run, if it were to be called at all). Additionally, make the current body of the observation handler conditional on `observe` and unconditionally set `observe` to `true` at its end. What do you think?

Comment: I think I still don't get the full picture of what the third party code is doing, what your code is doing, and what you want to (not) do in the resize observer callback.